# Iterate over django m2m through model objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following ManyToMany relationship in my project:

```
class Borrador(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        help_text=_('Nombre para identificar al borrador.')
    )
    productos = models.ManyToManyField(
        Producto,
        through=Articulo,
    )

class Articulo(models.Model):

    producto = models.ForeignKey(
        Producto,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    borrador = models.ForeignKey(
        'Borrador',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    unidades = models.IntegerField(
        default=1
    )

class Producto(models.Model):

    nombre_amistoso = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        help_text=_('Nombre corto para identificarlo facilmente.'),
        verbose_name=_('Pseudónimo')
    )
    nombre_fabricante = models.CharField(
        max_length=60,
        help_text=_(
            'Nombre largo que le da el fabricante al producto.'
        ),
        verbose_name=_('Nombre real')
    )
    fabricante = models.ForeignKey(
        'Fabricante',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    # etc...
```

As you can see, Articulo model acts as a through intermediary model to retrieve additional info.
I'm trying to iterate over all the Articulo objects associated with a given Borrador object.
At the moment I got it working by doing this:

```
class Borrador(models.Model):

    # [...]

    def tramitar(self, usuario, solicitar=False):

        articulos = self.productos.through.objects.filter(
            borrador=self
        )
        for articulo in articulos:
            # do stuff
```

My first attempt was the one below, but it returns **all** Articulo objects in the database

```
articulos = self.productos.through.objects.all()
for articulo in articulos:
    # do stuff
```

Is there a better way to do this? I imagined a simple `self.productos.through` shoul work, but it isn't the case...

Thanks in advance!
J.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `Borrador.Articulo.all()`?

Comment: Haven't tried, but I think Willem's answer is the right answer anyway. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Articulo`s through the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) of the `ForeignKey`:

```
def tramitar(self, usuario, solicitar=False):
    articulos = self.articulo_set.all()
    # …
```

Comment: Oh damn, I was so focused on the m2m relationship that I forgot I have a ForeignKey I could use (as I've done multiple times in the same project). Thanks a lot!